# How to access ItemController from ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to invoke a function within ItemController / or set new property of the child ItemController from ArrayController.

For better picture

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ["product"],
    itemController: 'product',

    contentChanged: function() { //no idea how to initiate this, hence I use observes

        // How do I access the children controllers from here?
        // I had tried below, but not working:
        // this.get("content").forEach(function(item) {
        //      item.doSomething(); 
        // });

    }.observes('content')

});

App.ProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    doSomething: function() {
       //supposed to do something
    }
});
```

I have not found any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies on "observes". The "content" changes way before the models are being wrapped correctly in the itemController (in this case is App.ProductController).

Hence the correct way to observe changes is to override the

```
//in App.ProductsController (aka Parent Controller)
arrayContentDidChange: function(startIdx, removeAmt, addAmt) {
    this._super(startIdx, removeAmt, addAmt);

    //then look for the children as such:
    this.forEach(function(item){
         item.doSomething();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be forEach on arrayController instance itself. `this.get("content")` here returns array of models, that are not wrapped in itemController

```
this.forEach(function(item) {
  item.doSomething(); 
});
```

Comment: Nope, the "this.forEach" does not iterate through subControllers at all.

Comment: Ok, correction, you are right that the "this.forEach" returns the itemController. I found out that the problem is actually at "observes". I will post a correct way of waiting for solution below. Thank you anyway! Gave u a +1